# Regex to parse 15 mins files only and skip 60 mins files

Tags: regex

we have below file formats

```
60min-->
A20210217.0300-0000-0400-0000_GBM053.xml.gz

15min -->
A20210217.0300-0000-0315-0000_GBM053.xml.gz ,A20210217.0315-0000-0330-0000_GBM053.xml.gz, A20210217.0330-0000-0345-0000_GBM053.xml.gz , A20210217.0345-0000-0400-0000_GBM053.xml.gz
```

Tried with below regex but not working

```
!(^A[0-9]{8}.[0-9]{2}[0]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}[0]{2}-[0-9]{4}_.*.xml(|\.gz)$)
```

Comment: Will all 60 minute file names be "top of the hour" like your example, or could they be like "A20210217.0315-0000-0415-0000_GBM053.xml.gz"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` at the start of the pattern matches a ! literally which is not there in the example data. If it was meant as a delimiter, it should also be at the end.

You could make the second part match either 15, 30 or 45 and use an alternation to those values either in the first or in the third part of the hyphened string.

```
^A\d{8}\.(?:\d\d(?:[14]5|30)(?:-\d{4}){3}|\d{4}-\d{4}-\d\d(?:[14]5|30)-\d{4})_.*\.xml\.gz$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `A\d{8}\.` Match `A` and 8 digits followed by a `.`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation to match either

  - `\d\d(?:[14]5|30)` Match 2 digits and either 15 or 45 or 30
  - `(?:-\d{4}){3}` Match 3 times `-` and 4 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{4}-\d{4}-` Match 2 times 4 digits and `-`
  - `\d\d(?:[14]5|30)-\d{4}` Match 2 digits and either 15 or 45 or 30 followed by 4 digits
- `)` Close non capture groups
- `_.*\.xml\.gz` Match `_`, 0+ times any char except a newline and `.xml.gz`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qq1QJD/1)

Comment: Thanks for your quick repliy. But we are getting all files like below.
A20210217.0300-0000-0315-0000_GBM053.xml.gz
A20210217.0315-0000-0330-0000_GBM053.xml.gz
A20210217.0330-0000-0345-0000_GBM053.xml.gz
A20210217.0345-0000-0400-0000_GBM053.xml.gz

Comment: @MuskanGargBansal Does that pattern have to be more specific? `^15min\s*-->\r?\n(A\d{8}\.\d{4}(?:-\d{4}){3}_.*\.xml\.gz)` See https://regex101.com/r/tdJpln/1

Comment: Here we are getting files after every 15 mins and 60 mins in same folder with same pattern. So i am looking for regex that can parse only 15 mins files and skip 60 mins files.

Comment: @MuskanGargBansal Like this you mean `^A\d{8}\.\d{4}-\d{4}-\d\d(?:[14]5|30)-\d{4}_.*\.xml\.gz$` https://regex101.com/r/DCHiNI/1

Comment: You are champ . It worked in my lab. Let me move to Customer env and Check. You are champ (y)

Comment: Hey it will not fulfill one condition 45th hour 00 hour. A20210217.0345-0000-0300-0000_GBM053.xml.gz

Comment: @MuskanGargBansal In that case you can use an alternation to match both options `^A\d{8}\.(?:\d\d(?:[14]5|30)(?:-\d{4}){3}|\d{4}-\d{4}-\d\d(?:[14]5|30)-\d{4})_.*\.xml\.gz$` https://regex101.com/r/qq1QJD/1

Comment: Thanks Champ it worked . On my system it worked after replacing / with //.
Final regex: ^A\\d{8}\\.(?:\\d\\d(?:[14]5|30)(?:-\\d{4}){3}|\\d{4}-\\d{4}-\\d\\d(?:[14]5|30)-\\d{4})_.*.xml.*$

Comment: I tried to vote your answer but seems i am new to this and dont have reputation to do so. i will keep a note once i will have will do surely.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/KqB81T/2

`^A\d{8}\.(\d{2}(?:[14]5|30)-0000-\d{4}-0000|\d{4}-0000-\d{2}(?:[14]5|30)-0000)_.*\.xml(|\.gz)$`

Break down structure:

- First two entries are matched: `\d{2}(?:[14]5|30)-0000-\d{4}-0000`
- Last two entries are matched: `\d{4}-0000-\d{2}(?:[14]5|30)-0000`

Add matches (UNION between the two SET matches): `(FIRST_MATCH|SECOND_MATCH)`. Also make sure you don't have any character/space at the end (between `gz` and `$`)

Let me be the first to say: Welcome to SO, [Muskan Garg Bansal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15227475/muskan-garg-bansal)!

Comment: Thanks BondanBiv. Stakoverflow is really hepful as i have seen.
it worked with below regex: ^A\\d{8}\\.(?:\\d\\d(?:[14]5|30)(?:-\\d{4}){3}|\\d{4}-\\d{4}-\\d\\d(?:[14]5|30)-\\d{4})_.*.xml.*$